# Java Serialization with Multiple Inheritance?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I'm learning and attempting Java Serialization. My code has Inheritance and follows the structure

```
Scaffold -> Game.java -> Goals (abstract) -> (extended by) -> GoalsExtender
```

I have a deserialization method in Scaffold (dummy) class with opens can open `game.ser` serializable data and cast it to `(Game)`. So, I cannot directly pass an serialized data for `GoalsExtender` itself else It will create a class cast exception.

Here is my `Goals.java`

```
public abstract class Goals {
private String score;

public Goals(String str) {
    this.score = str;
}

String getGoals() {
    return this.score;
}

   void doSomething(Context context) {
    }
 }
```

Here is my `Game.java`

```
public class Game implements Serializable {
    public String name;
    public int game_num;
    public int opp;
    public int player;
    public Goals goal;

    public Game(int i, int i2, int i3) {
        this.player = i;
        this.game_num = i2;
        this.opp = i3;
    }

    public Game(String str, Goals goal) {
        this.name = str;
        this.goal = goal;
    }

}
```

Here is `GoalsExtender.java`

```
public class GoalsExtender extends Goals implements Serializable {
 private String team_name;
 private String club_name;
 private String player_name;

   public GoalsExtender(String team_name, String club_name, String player_name) {
        super(team_name);
        this.club_name = club_name;
        this.player_name = player_name;
    }

   void doSomething(Context context){
         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         stringBuilder.append(player_name);
         stringBuilder.append(" has scored for");
         stringBuilder.append(team_name);

  }
```

The questions are :

1.) Can you pass a `Game` serialized object which can set `club_name` and `player_name` inside the `GoalsExtender.java` when it is deserialized and casted to `(Game)` type? (A local POJO creation approach is also fine)

Comment: can you provide example of what exactly you want to do? Also `Goals` class probably should implements serializable too